# FetchResults<T>.Element cannot convert into T - SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, struct, swiftui, type-conversion

I have a problem with databases. I want to pass a user into another view as depicted below:
[image]

And as you can see I get an error that I cannot convert this Element into User.

My user strut looks like this:

```
struct User: Decodable, Identifiable {
    public let id: String
    public let name: String
    public let age: Int16
    public let company: String
    public let about: String
    public let isActive: Bool
    public let email: String
    public let address: String
    public let registered: String
}
```

and my user database looks like that:

[image]

Does anyone know what may be a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are fetching CoreData entity objects, but you are trying to cast a CoreData entity object to a struct type.

UserList is a CoreData entity object. The fetching is correct. However, UserView needs a object of `User`.

**Solution 1:** Convert your UserList to a User element.

**Solution 2:** Pass the User object to your UserView

```
struct UserView : View {

    var userList : UserList  // << Type of UserList
```

Comment: No problem! I can recommend to use @FetchRequest wrapper. It makes it even more easy to fetch something in SwiftUI from CoreData with just on line.     `@FetchRequest(entity: UserList.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var users : FetchedResults<UserList>`